# How do I link to a meta tag in the main site?

Tags: support, markdown

So, as you know, if you write a tag, like so:

[minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

```
[tag:minecraft]
```

SE automatically converts that into the relevant site's tag link and formats it nicely like the ones at the bottom of the question, or so to say, like these ones:

[image]

---

How would I do that with a meta tag? I know meta doesn't adhere to the tags either, for example, the example above goes to the main site's `minecraft` tagged questions.

How would I say, make it format like a tag, but link to a meta tag page instead, without using hyperlinks?

For example, the main site doesn't have a [status-bydesign](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag... But [meta does](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

(And no, don't go creating it, because that's not the point of the question)

Ninja Edit: Also, there's an SSL error for `gaming.meta.stackexchange.com`. Could be cache though.

Comment: I know in chat `[meta-tag:wharrgarbl]` is a thing but I'll have to test to be certain

Comment: Curious, why do you want to reference a meta tag on the main site?  I can see the use case for referencing main site tags on meta, but not really the other way around.

Comment: @Unionhawk also, according to the [Markdown page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) "`meta-tag` only works on meta sites." Although is it listed under the comment formatting section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you'll need to use a standard link, e.g:

`[Support](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support)`